# dynamically creating objects

Tags: java

I have a method that receives an array of strings and I need to create objects with appropriate names.

For example:

```
public class temp {    
   public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] a=new String[3];
    a[0]="first";
    a[1]="second";
    a[2]="third";
    createObjects(a);

   }
   public static void createObjects(String[] s)
   {
    //I want to have integers with same names
    int s[0],s[1],s[2];
   }
}
```

If I receive ("one","two") I must create:

```
Object one;
Object two;
```

If I receive ("boy","girl") I must create:

```
Object boy;
Object girl;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably you haven't yet used the *collection framework* available in Java.

Comment: What do you mean, "with appropriate names"? Are you trying to create objects which have a name property? Or do you actually want to have classes called "first", "second", etc? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

Can't do that in java. You can instead create a `Map` who's keys are the strings and the values are the objects.

Comment: but I don't know with which names create objects, it will be known only at execution

Comment: the map IS populated at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

First create `Map` which contains the key as String representation of `Integers`.

```
public class Temp {

static Map<String, Integer> lMap;

static {

    lMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    lMap.put("first", 1);
    lMap.put("second", 2);
    lMap.put("third", 3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> lMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] a = new String[3];
    a[0] = "first";
    a[1] = "second";
    a[2] = "third";

    Integer[] iArray=createObjects(a);
    for(Integer i:iArray){

        System.out.println(i);
    }

}

public static Integer[] createObjects(String[] s) {
    // I want to have integers with same names
    Integer[] number = new Integer[s.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        number[i] = lMap.get(s[i]);
    }
    return number;
}

}
```

Comment: you misunderstand me :) integers are examples. I mean:
if I receive ("one","two") I must create:
    Object one;
    Object two;
if I receive ("boy","girl") I must create:
    Object boy;
    Object girl;